# <a href=""> does not go to another page when pass value

Tags: php

I have a display_all_groups.php page that display a bootstrap card of all groups created by user. When users click on "View Group" hyperlink it will direct them to view_group.php

Here are my code

```php
session_start();
require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/mindspace/Business Services Layer/ManageGroupsController/GroupsController.php';

$std_id = $_SESSION['std_id'];

$group = new ManageGroupsController();
$data = $group->viewGroups($std_id);
?>      
      
      <div class="main-panel">
        <div class="content-wrapper">  
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
              <form method="post">
              <?php
                foreach($data as $row){
              ?>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="../../template/images/banner.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title"><?=$row['group_name']?></h5>
                      <p class="card-text"></p>
                      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="view_group.php?group_id=<?=$row['group_id']?>">View Group</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
              <?php } ?>   
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

When I try to click on the View Group button, it did not bring me to other page that I want it to. Please help, Im very new to PHP

Comment: You have am extra single quota  after ?>  .. try remove it

Comment: @ScaisEdge I removed it but nothing changes.

Comment: @MunirahShamsudin If you hover the link you see the right url?

Comment: @MaikLowrey no. the button wont even click. it does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what the problem could be. First I would always check that $data is not empty. Then the keys are named correctly. I don't know the data object.

If everything is correct, then it should work. A small note: In the link there is still a simple quotation mark. You should delete that too.

`<?= $row['group_id']?>  >>>>**'**<<<< "`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php session_start();
require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/mindspace/Business Services Layer/ManageGroupsController/GroupsController.php';

$std_id = $_SESSION['std_id'];

$group = new ManageGroupsController();
$data = $group->viewGroups($std_id);
?>

<div class="main-panel">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
                <form method="post">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($data as $row) {
                    ?>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="../../template/images/banner.png" alt="Card image cap">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title"><? echo $row['group_name']; ?></h5> <!-- Used echo -->
                                    <p class="card-text"></p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="view_group.php?group_id=<? echo $row['group_id']; ?>">View Group</a> <!-- used echo, removed extra single quote -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </form>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I had done a few changes in the code,

1. Used `echo`
2. Removed an additional single quote